# Issue (bug?) with MonetDB.R and dbWriteTable with csvdump=TRUE

Tags: r, monetdb

We are managing to write 1.7 M rows in 30s or so (on a MacBook Pro) using R and MonetDB.R within a shiny application:

```
dbWriteTable(conn, tableName, Dt,overwrite=TRUE, csvdump=TRUE)
```

As we understand the MonetDB.R code saves first in a `/tmp` folder the table in a `csv` format, then is loaded onto the MonetDB database with `COPY INTO`

We have just tried on a centos server and RStudio Server and we got an access right error on the temporary folder in `/tmp`.

We resolved the problem with the classic

```
chmod -R 777 /tmp
```

But it seems we have to do it again if we run this part of the app within shiny hence it does not look a scalable solution.

Would it be possible to get a more stable & scalable solution?

(also, this feature was documented in MonetDB 0.94 but it does not appear anywhere in the 0.95 document on CRAN - can we safely assume that this is a typo and the feature is going to stay?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MonetDB.R` uses R's `tempfile()` to create the temporary CSV file. `tempfile` in turn calls `tempdir` to get a temporary directory. You can control the location of this directory through the environment variable `TMPDIR` and others. See `?tempdir` for details.

e.g.

```
$ TMPDIR=/tmp/foo R -e "print(tempfile())"
[1] "/tmp/bar/Rtmp7UKG0k/file1173e13a4477c"

$ TMPDIR=/tmp/bar R -e "print(tempfile())"
[1] "/tmp/foo/RtmpPxx76t/file1174a409c06a2"
```

With regards to your other question, the csvdump feature is going to remain, since MonetDB is quite fast at bulk CSV loading.